# How to detect keystrokes which don't edit the buffer?

Tags: key-bindings

What's the best way to detect keystrokes (e.g. via a hook) which don't edit the buffer? I mean things like arrow-keys for point motion, calls to `beginning-of-buffer`, etc.

The reason for this is that I'm working on some `ycmd` bindings for emacs, and I'd like to be able to detect (at least heuristically) when the user has stopped editing and is moving around the buffer. This is a good time for shipping the buffer contents off for parsing. The vim client does this when the user exits insertion mode, and I'm trying to emulate that behavior.

Comment: You may be interested in idle timers for this kind of stuff: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html

Comment: Another idea (or a refinement of the idea with idle timers): advise `self-insert-command` to cancel and reschedule a timer instead of using an idle timer.  This way, even if the user *does* something, the timer is not reset unless the "something" is text insertion.

Comment: mbork: `after-change-functions` is a general mechanism for reacting to text changes.

Comment: Use a `post-command-hook`. That will trigger on everything, so you may need to do some filtering on what triggered it before taking whatever action you want.

Comment: malabarba: it's the "do some filtering" bit that I was hoping to avoid having to invent. I need a sort of `after-non-change-functions` hook.

Comment: Not sure it's relevant for this particular problem, but the `buffer-chars-modified-tick` function may be useful.

Comment: Interesting! It just might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following hooks:

- To `pre-command-hook`, set some sentinel variable to `t` – this signals the command was non-changing.
- To `after-change-functions`, set this sentinel value to `nil`.  (It is a hook, it just doesn't sound like one; thanks to @phils for pointing this out.)
- To `post-command-hook`, check this sentinel value and run your function.

This may or may not work depending on the order of execution.  If it doesn't, let me know in the comments below.

---

When I get off work, I will post an example.

Comment: I have to go to work now…

Comment: Don't advise self insert. Use after-change-functions

Comment: I'll give this a shot when I've got a chance.

Comment: Malabarba: Why should I prefer one over the other? This seems like something worth knowing.

Comment: @abingham As a general rule, hooks are preferable to advices. Hooks are specifically designed for you to attach functions, while advices are ways to attach something in unexpected places. In this particular case, it's also not advisable to advise some very fundamental functions, because it interacts unreliably with byte compilation.

Comment: I think Sean meant to refer to `post-self-insert-hook` (that bit of the answer seems to be confusing that hook with advising `self-insert-command`). In any case, I think you would generally prefer `after-change-functions` because it actually does what you want (as self-insert is *not* the only kind of key stroke which modifies the buffer).

Comment: @phils I should have read the comments closer!  And yes, that fact is obvious with Org's structural editing :) It would have been a shortcoming if it weren't for `after-change-functions`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought -

This should not really be about "keystrokes", but about *commands* - no matter how they are executed, *no*?  If I understand correctly, you are really looking for a way to tell whether a given command that gets invoked modifies the buffer.

If so, then maybe do something like this:

- Put a function on `pre-command-hook` that (1) records the current value of `(buffer-modified-p)` and then (2) uses `set-modified-p` to make the buffer unmodified.
- Put a function on `post-command-hook` that (1) checks whether the command modified the buffer (by comparing the recorded value against the new current value of `(buffer-modified-p)`), then acts accordingly, and (2) if the new value is `nil` then resets to the pre-change value using `set-modified-p`.

Kind of heavy-handed (it checks for each command that is invoked), but it might be worth a try.

If the "*acts accordingly*" part is just a no-op for all buffer modifying commands, and if it is also a no-op for many non-modifying commands (e.g. because you just did it on a previous non-modifying command), then at least you will not be doing that "*acts accordingly*" action more than necessary.  But the checking part alone might be expensive/overkill (slow things down too much) - try it to see.